# Don't lose input focus on clicking on overlapped element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, overlay

[image]

I have the above widget which has the below DOM:

### HTML :

```
<div>
    <div class="eye" onclick="toggleEye(event);">
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS :

```
.eye {
   position: 'absolute';
   right: 30px,
   margin-top:10px
}
```

If you know CSS, you will conclude that `<i />` & `<input:password>` are overlapped.

**I want to not lose input focus when I click on the overlapped element which is `<i />` .**

I tried with `event.target` , `event.currentTarget` and `event.relatedTarget`.. However , .. in vain ,, no solution

```
toggleEye(e){
   if(!e.target.tagName==='INPUT'){
       // don't lose on-focus  : How to ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If overlapped element is just for styling you can use CSS property `pointer-events`.

By setting `pointer-events:none` to overlapped element, click event will be triggered on the necessary element.

Comment: It doesn't work on my side, if I set it on the input, we can't click on the input anymore, if I set it on the eye, we can't click on the Eye, and the eye has javascript functions